# How to export multiple header files as a single header file in C++?

Tags: c++, dll, header-files

I'm developing a DLL using Visual Studio. Currently, I have one header file: `MyProject.h`:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MYLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MYLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <map>
#include <string>

extern "C" class MYLIBRARY_API Class1
{
    // some stuff here...
};

extern "C" class MYLIBRARY_API Class2
{
    // some stuff here
};
```

I am going to be adding some more classes to the project and I would like to add separate header files for each class (please advise if I should not do that). However, eventually, I want to package all that into a single .dll and .lib in such a way that the client only needs to include a single header file. That is, the client project has `#include "MyProject.h"` which is essentially a collection of header files with their implmentation files. Is this possible and how can I achieve this? Thanks.

EDIT:

To be specific, what I want to do is to put `Class1` in `Class1.h` and `Class2` in `Class2.h` and include both of them in one master header file called `MyLibrary.h` so that a client only have to do `#include "MyLibrary.h"`.

Comment: A tip : Avoid using any types from the standard library in your DLL interface since these are compiler and version implementation specific. Which means that if you and your clients use different compilers or even different version of the same compiler your code will break !

Comment: @engf-010 is this true even if the DLL is distributed as a pre-compiled binary?

Comment: yes this is a well known issue with DLLs and using the standard library in their interfaces. If you need to use them (you can internally) you should not expose them over dll-boundaries. stick to your own types and/or c-compatible types.

Comment: @engf-010 Thank you very much for that valuable advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have several header files like A.h, B.h etc and want to give the client just Project.h that includes all, then simply include all the headers in Project.h - like so:

```
#ifndef MY_PROJECT_H
#define MY_PROJECT_H
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#endif
```

Comment: I am trying your solution but every time I get: "Cannot open include file: "file.h" No such file or directory" . I am trying to generate a static library (.lib). Does this solution apply only to .dll generation?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry ,I misunderstood what you were asking.

Yes, you can have multiple header-files that are included in your library header-file (be sure to include them with `#include "..."`).

if you want to eliminate the need of specifying library in the linker-section (this is what I thought you were asking) ,with MSVC++ the thing you're looking for is

```
#pragma comment( comment-type [,"commentstring"] )
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp

Comment: I went through the link, but still a bit confused... Could you show a concrete example? I have updated my question to show my full code write now.

Comment: if you use #pragma comment( lib ,"your-libname.lib" ) the compiler inserts a library request in your object-file so that you don't need to specify that library manually for the linker. (that's what I think you were asking)

Comment: @engf-010 That's a completely tool-chain dependant solution. A portable solution would be to use a build system to link the right stuff on the right platforms with the right compilers. Don't hardcore stuff like that in source files in tool-chain specific ways. Strive for portable, platform and compiler agnostic code.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl:What the ... are you talking about ? Normally I would agee with you ,but this about a DLL which implies Windows Development which makes any mention of a toolchain just silly and FYI hardcode library pragma's in dll-header is not uncommon or rare and sometimes even desirable !

Comment: @engf-010 One can use different compilers on Windows. Both MSVC, clang, GCC and ICC work well there, and probably others as well.