# Can you create multiple header files for a DLL? Can you consolidate header files?

Tags: c++, dll, header-files

*Background: I'm using Project Euler as an excuse to test various C++ features and find holes in my knowledge. I have a project that creates an executable which solves various math problems. It's getting unwieldy and I'm splitting the problems out into separate executables. A lot of the math functions are re-used in several of the problems.*

**First:** I want to create a DLL file with math helper functions. Rather than provide one single `mathhelp.h` file for the entire dll, I'd prefer to have several separate `.h` files e.g. `primes.h`, `cartesian.h` etc./ that each provide access to separate namespaces in the dll.

Is this possible?

**Second:** Separately, I *do* want a single `mathhelp.h` file for those projects big enough they just need access to every helper function without including fifty separate headers. How to do this is answered in:

[How to export multiple header files as a single header file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985779/how-to-export-multiple-header-files-as-a-single-header-file-in-c)

but that answer gives me a follow-up question: If, in an executable project, I include the following header from the DLL project:

```
#ifndef MATHHELP_H
#define MATHHELP_H
#include "primes.h"
#include "cartesian.h"
#endif
```

...how does that compile if I don't also have `primes.h` in the executable project? Won't the pre-compiler reach the first `#include` and choke on the fact that I don't have `primes.h` in the project?

Comment: I have created `dlls` with over a hundred header files. Because of the concept of using 1 header per class.

Comment: But were they exposed to the user of the DLL, or were they internal?

Comment: Yes they are exposed in the dll.

Comment: The answer from @Marga is very close to what I do. Also similar to large opensource software like `vtk`, `itk` and `Qt`

Comment: You have to tell the compiler where mathhelp.h is located.  By setting the INCLUDE environment variable for example, or whatever mechanism your favorite IDE uses.  As long as you keep all of those other .h files in the same directory then you don't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide a c++ compiled API to a user ( let's say it is compiled in a `.dll` file) you should provide beside the `.dll` file also the `.h` files (containg all header that were used to compile that `.dll`) and `.lib`files ( containg the exported symbols from that .`dll` ).
Now let's say that your user has the executable `a.exe`, and wants to use your compiled API. Usually you will provide them a file structure which looks more or less like that :

```
include / primes.h
          cartesian.h
          mathhelp.h

lib     / Api.lib

bin     / Api.dll
```

When an external executable uses your code he will need to add external flags in the compilation procedure like : `-I/pathToInclude -L/PathToLib -l/yourLibrary` ( you need to check the exact sintax for doing that).
In your code you  you will have something like this:

```
#ifndef MATHHELP_H
#define MATHHELP_H
#include <primes.h>
#include <cartesian.h>
#endif
```

In this case the compiler will look firstly in the current directory ( where he won't find the headers) and then in the folders specified by the `-I` flag ( where he will find your headers).

Comment: "containg all header that were used to compile that" - I was under the impression (from the linked question) that this is unnecessary, and that you can do something to provide only one single header file with the DLL. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: you will need either all the headers ( as I wrote above) OR you if you know exactly what are the exported function of the .dll you are using, you can use function like LoadLibrary("yourdll") and GetProcAddress("yourMethod") and execute the function through function pointer and in this case there is no need of the headers.

Comment: In some cases you can do that (consolidate the headers down to a single header) however it may be difficult to do. And in the case of a large library it does not really help the user that much anyways.